# Eclipse not creating main.xml with adt plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, program-entry-point, generated

I am working on windows 7 and I am trying to create an app. I followed the my first app procedure on the android site (i have also done this in windows xp at work and it was fine) but now something is not right. When I create my android project it does not generate a main.xml file, rather activity_my_first.xml. I followed all the instructions correctly, I reinstalled everything configured all the plugins the same way i did at work. I tried to follow the instructions on this page http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html
and it gives me the errors : Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').

I'm confused because i followed the same instructions at work and the app worked just fine in xp. I cant figure out whats going on here.

Comment: Name of the layout file does not matter, as of missing string resource - just remove links to it if you don't need it, or create it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The recent updates to ADT have made a few changes:

1. layout XML file for activities you add using the wizard are named like `activiy_<activityname>.xml` instead of older naming convention.
2. The wizard also automatically generates menu layout xml of same name as above in **res/menu** folder and adds `onCreateContextMenu(..` to the activity source.
3. And finally it adds String values to **values/strings.xml** for menu xml created above, it looks like:

> ```
> <resources>
>     <string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
>     <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
>     <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
>     <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
> </resources>
> ```

Looks like the `menu_settings` value is missing from this XML, or the XML file is missing in your case.

Comment: ohh ok. Its changes in the ADT then, I guess they haven't updated their beginner tutorials to account for that yet.